# Dependency Injection with PowerMock & Mockito

Tags: dependency-injection, mockito, powermock

How do I create a JUnit testcase for the following class with PowerMock & Mockito.
The class I want to inject is a final class so I'll need to use PowerMock to mock it.
Also note I would prefer to use DI rather than a setter to inject it.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ObjectA {

    // Use DI to Inject a mock for this 'final' class
    @Inject
    private ObjectB objectB;

    public ObjectA() {
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        if (null == this.objectB) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to inject ObjectB");
        }

        this.objectB.someOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for PowerMock at this point. Mockito can do all the work.

```
public class ObjectATest
{
    @Mock
    private ObjectB objectB;

    @InjectMocks
    private ObjectA objectA;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            objectA.someMethod();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e)
        {
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is Mockito can't mock the final class ObjectB

Comment: If you are agreed that your answer is incorrect, you can successfully delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Whitebox](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/BypassEncapsulation) class. For example let's say you've created a mock of `ObjectB` called `objectBMock` and an instance of `ObjectA` called `objectA`:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(objectA, objectBMock);
```

This will "inject" `objectBMock` to `objectA`.